# Output filename/lines/type for given directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to teach myself basic file manipulation and scripting in linux but I've hit a wall. Right now I'm trying to output a table that gives something like

```
FILENAME     LINES     TYPE
File1        22        File
File2        56        File
Folder1      N/A       Directory
```

when given any directory to search. I've been researching how to format output using awk and using maybe grep and wc to try and get my data but I'm a bit lost. For all I know I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely.

Comment: have you tried anything? ...or homework ?

Comment: I would use a for loop, and the `wc` and `file` or `stat` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `printf` to format your output, then look at the commands `file` to find your file type, `wc` to print out the number of lines, etc.

All this could be done via a `find | while read` loop:

```
printf "%-20.20s   %-3.3s   %s\n", "File", "Lines", "Type"
find . -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
file_name=$(basename $file)
    lines="$(cat $file | wc -l | sed 's/^  *//')"
    desc="$(file --brief "$file")"
printf "%-20.20s   %3.3s   %s\n", "$file_name", $lines, "$desc"
done
```

The `$(...)` syntax returns the output of the enclosed command as a string that can be assigned to variable. I use `cat $file | wc -l` to eliminate the name of the file, and then use `sed` to remove leading spaces.